# Append table with images from Firebase

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to append table with images. But for some reason it is not displaying them. What can cause this?

This is the `jquery`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var brandsRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Snuses");
    brandsRef.on("child_added", snap=> {
        var productImageUrl = snap.child("productUrl").val(); //This is the image src
        var brandName = snap.child("Brand").val();
        var product = snap.child("Products").val();
        var nicotine = snap.child("nicotine").val();

        $("#tableBody").append("<tr>"
            + "<td>"+$("img").attr("src", productImageUrl);+"</td>" //Is this right way to do it?
            + "<td>"+brandName+"</td>"
            + "<td>"+product+"</td>"
            + "<td>"+nicotine+"</td>"
            + "</tr>");

    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("img")` just grabs all the images on the page as it's treated as a CSS selector. What you probably wanted was `$("<img/>")`.

In general, your code should probably look something like:

```
var $row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo('#tableBody');
$('<td></td>').appendTo($row).append($('<img />').attr('src', productImageUrl));
$('<td></td>').appendTo($row).text(brandName);
$('<td></td>').appendTo($row).text(product);
$('<td></td>').appendTo($row).text(nicotine);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. Your code is much cleaner also yes :)